# Cargo build package with conflicting features from the same git repository?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a git repository (not crates.io) which has different features, let’s call them A and B, which are mutually exclusive - the two features expose structs and API of the same names, hence compiling both naively will result in conflicts and fail.

As a developer of a dependant package, I want to use both features.
I can use aliasing. It fails if I use the same git repository url, but it works if in Cargo.toml I use two different git repositories:

```
[dependencies]
my_package_A = {package = "my_package", git = "/first/url", features = ["A"]}
my_package_B = {package = "my_package", git = "/second/url", features = ["B"]}
```

I want to avoid forking my repository to a different url.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Even if you manage to solve this particular problem, your approach will always be brittle. Cargo tries to use only one instance of a crate in a dependency graph whenever the constraints allow, and the required features are simply merged. So if there is one crate in your dependency graph depending on your crate with feature `A`, and a different, unrelated crate depending on a compatible version with feature `B`, Cargo will merge these two into a single dependency with both features enabled. Features are simply not intended to be used this way, and I suggest you rethink this design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargo features allow to mark parts of the code as *optional*, mainly to allow making some of the dependencies of a library optional. They are not meant to be used as a general software configuration mechanism.

In the situation you describe, I suggest splitting up your crate into three crates: One with the base functionality, one for feature `A` and one for feature `B`. You can keep these three crates in a single Cargo workspace and a single Git repository. Dependent crates can then choose what parts they would like to dependent on, and Cargo will resolve this as intended even for larger dependency graphs with multiple instances of your crate.